# refreshApex in Lightning Web Components is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, refreshapex

In Custom Object i have new tab with lightning Input, On Save the Form value we need to Display the data in data table.

Data is saving in my object, But Data-table is not refreshing with new data.

I'm using `refreshApex` but not sure It;s not working, Can Anyone help me on this.

```
   <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={priceAdjustmentData} hide-checkbox-column="true"
            columns={priceAdjustmentColumns} draft-values={draftValues} resize-column-disabled="true">
        </lightning-datatable>
```

```
  import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";

  @api recordId;
  @track priceAdjustmentError;
  @track priceAdjustmentData;
  wiredPriceAdjustDataRefresh;
  @wire(getPriceAdjustment, { studentProgramId: "$recordId" })
  priceAdjustment(priceAdjresponse) {
  this.wiredPriceAdjustDataRefresh = priceAdjresponse;
    const priceAdjustmentdata = priceAdjresponse.data;
    const priceAdjustmenterror = priceAdjresponse.error;
    // let responseJson = JSON.stringify(priceAdjustmentdata);
    // console.log("priceAdjustmentData -->" + responseJson);
    if (priceAdjustmentdata) {
      // this.priceAdjustmentData = priceAdjustmentdata;
      this.priceAdjustmentData = priceAdjustmentdata.map((record) =>
        Object.assign(
          {
            Billing_Name:
              record.Billing_Process__r.Billing_Period_Name__c
          },
          record
        )
      );
      console.log("this.priceAdjustmentData" + this.priceAdjustmentData);
    } else if (priceAdjustmenterror) {
      this.priceAdjustmentError = priceAdjustmenterror;
    }
  }


 refreshapex() {
    return refreshApex(this.wiredPriceAdjustDataRefresh);
  }

createPriceAdjustment() {
    const allValid = [
      ...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")
    ].reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
      inputCmp.reportValidity();
      return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
    }, true);

    const allValid1 = [
      ...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-textarea")
    ].reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
      inputCmp.reportValidity();
      return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
    }, true);

    if (allValid && allValid1) {
      alert("valid");
      createPriceAdjustment({
        studentProgramId: this.recordId,
        billingProcessId: this.billingProcess,
        priceAdjustment: this.priceAdjustment,
        reasonforAdjustment: this.priceAdjustmentReason
      })
        .then((result) => {
          if (result) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "Success",
                message: "New Price Adjustment created",
                variant: "success"
              })
            );
            this.billingProcessName = "";
            this.priceAdjustment = "";
            this.priceAdjustmentReason = "";
            this.priceAfterAdjustment = "";
             return refreshApex(this.wiredPriceAdjustDataRefresh);
          } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "Error",
                message: "Error creating record",
                variant: "error"
              })
            );
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
              title: "Error",
              message: "Error creating record",
              variant: "error"
            })
          );
          console.log("error -->" + error);
        });
    }
  }
```

**Inspect element Getting following error**

```
aura_prod.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[this._cmp[this._wireTarget] is not a function]
    at b.dispatchEvent (aura_prod.js:6)
    at yi (lds.js:2)
    at eval (lds.js:2)
    at Object.broadcast (lds.js:2)
    at Object.storeBroadcast (lds.js:2)
    at Object.e.<computed> [as storeBroadcast] (lds.js:2)
    at eval (lds.js:2)
```

Comment: Where you have defined `recordId`, where is it coming from?

Comment: @api recordId above the Wire method, It's the current page Record Id

Comment: Can you share what is being logged out in the console

Answer (score 0):

```
wiredResults;
@wire(getPriceAdjustment, { studentProgramId: "$recordId" })
  priceAdjustment(result) {
    this.wiredResults = result;
     if(result.data) {
       console.log(result.data);
     }else if(result.error){
       console.log(result.error);
     }
}
refreshapex(){
   return refreshApex(this.wiredResults); 
}
```

Comment: Edited my code, Still not working

Comment: you need to set `priceAdjustment(result) `

Comment: what is the difference of  `priceAdjustment(result)` `priceAdjustment(priceAdjresponse)`, Both should behave the same, it's return value.

Comment: i don't think so that `refreshapex` have problem in your code ,

Comment: tried that too, Still no luck